# CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate() and JsDate.setMonth() giving wrong date in GWT

Tags: gwt

In case of last Month End date is 31st Aug 2018 and I want to get the last three month's Month End date that is 30th June 2018 but using CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate() and JsDate's setMonth() both the API giving me date as 1st July 2018. See the below code for more details:

```
Date currentMonthFirstDate = new Date();
CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(currentMonthFirstDate);//1-Sep

//Setting the Last month end date
final Date lastMonthEndDate = CalendarUtil.copyDate(currentMonthFirstDate);
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(lastMonthEndDate, -1);//31st Aug

final Date lastThreeMonthEndDate = CalendarUtil.copyDate(lastMonthEndDate);
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(lastThreeMonthEndDate, -2);//Setting to 1st Sep but I want 30th june
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution for the same. So I will get the exact date regardless month is having 31 or 30 days.

PS: I can not use java.util.Calendar in GWT client side code.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the desired result :)

You have found the right way to jump to the end of a month: `setToFirstDayOfMonth`, then `addDaysToDate` (-1 day) will get you to the last day of the previous month.

If you look at the implementation of `addMonthsToDate` method, you'll see that it does not checks how many days there are in a given month. So, you can get *invalid* dates like `Feb 30th` or `Jun 31st`. Of course those dates will be automatically *fixed* to be `Mar 2nd` and `Jul 1st` respectively.

So you can not use `addMonthsToDate` method in this case. But you already know how to get the last day of the previous month - just use it two more times to get `lastThreeMonthEndDate`:

```
Date currentMonthFirstDate = new Date();
CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(currentMonthFirstDate);   //1st Sep

//Setting the Last month end date
final Date lastMonthEndDate = CalendarUtil.copyDate(currentMonthFirstDate);
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(lastMonthEndDate, -1);           //31st Aug

final Date lastThreeMonthEndDate = CalendarUtil.copyDate(lastMonthEndDate);
CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(lastThreeMonthEndDate);   //1st Aug
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(lastThreeMonthEndDate, -1);      //31st Jul
CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(lastThreeMonthEndDate);   //1st Jul
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(lastThreeMonthEndDate, -1);      //30th Jun
```

---

Just to consider: you can safely use `addMonthsToDate` method, provided that you  `setToFirstDayOfMonth` first. This way you'll not get *invalid* dates because day `1st` is valid for any month.